# Get Views from DialogFragment

Tags: java, android

Implemented a dialog fragement this way:

```
public class ProgressFragment extends DialogFragment {

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.installation_page, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    titleView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.progressText);
    titleView.setText("progress");
    builder.setView(v);
    return builder.create();
}

 TextView titleView;

public TextView getTextView() {
    return titleView;
}
```

and i want to be able to update content of titleView, from whereever it is called.
 like:

```
ProgressFragment progressFragment = new ProgressFragment();
progressFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"");
```

issue is triers like:

```
((TextView)progressFragment.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.progressText)).setText("text");
```

and

```
progressFragment.getTextView().setText("text");
```

and

```
((TextView)progressFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.progressText)).setText("working in this place");
```

all returns null. How do i do this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No! No! No!

if you create your DialogFragment with

```
 `Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)`
```

(*your View is dead*) as you created it with Dialog but not

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup
               container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Looking at your code i will suggest you use the second method of creating your DialogFrament as you are just return a `TextView` *cheese*

but if you insist on your method, then your solution is, quite longer

```
progressFragment.getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView()
```

the decorview might be your `TextView` *im not sure* but overall

```
 progressFragment.getDialog().getWindow().findViewById();
```

Comment: The view is not dead. It gets added to the alert dialog. It only becomes hard to get a reference on it at a later time. That's why, if you want to modify anything in the root view at a later time, you should keep a reference on it in your fragment and assign it to that reference, before returning out of the onCreateDialog()-method. In this case, he only modifies textview, so he can reference textview.

Answer (score 2):

Not so sure if this is a good practice but i fixed it using callbacks.

```
 public interface dialogViewCallBack {
    void onViewLoaded(TextView textView);
}

static dialogViewCallBack dialogViewCallBack;

public ProgressFragment progressFragment(dialogViewCallBack callBack) {
    dialogViewCallBack = callBack;
    return new ProgressFragment();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.installation_page, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    TextView titleView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.progressText);
    titleView.setText("progress");
    builder.setView(v);
    dialogViewCallBack.onViewLoaded(titleView);
    return builder.create();
}
```

So, on the class that call progressFragment, i just do:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ProgressFragment.dialogViewCallBack {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ProgressFragment progressFragment = new ProgressFragment().progressFragment(this);
    progressFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"");

}

@Override
public void onViewLoaded(TextView textView) {
    // can assign the view to another view here.
    textView.setText("working here");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a setter method for text view in Dialog Fragment

```
public void setTextView(String str) {
   titleView.setText(str);
}
```

and call

```
ProgressFragment progressFragment = new ProgressFragment();
progressFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"");
progressFragment.setTextView("title");
```

Comment: this means that your tetxview is null

Comment: textview is not null as it is seen on onCreateDialog

Answer (score 0):

```
 override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return activity?.let {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
        // Get the layout inflater
        val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater;

        // get custom layout view
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_dialog, null)
        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(view)
                // Add action buttons
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                            // sign in the user ...
                            val editText = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.channelName)
                            Toast.makeText(activity, editText.text.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                        })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                            getDialog()?.cancel()
                        })
        builder.create()
    } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
}
```

Comment: Replying with kotlin on a java question. very rude. Also kotlin is D E A D